# How to change UINavigationBar's label position (frame)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, uinavigationbar

I need it aligned to left. Or there is no way and I need to add custom label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself:

```
float offset = 210.0f;

UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, offset, 44.01)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];

[tools release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the left button item:

```
UIView *mCustView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,20)];

mCustView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UILabel *mTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,20)];

mTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

mTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];

mTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

mTextLabel.text = @"Random text tested here, so sit back and enjoy";

[mCustView addSubview:mTextLabel];

[mTextLabel release];


UIBarButtonItem *mCustomBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mCustView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mCustomBarItem; 

[mCustView release];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but there is a problem, the old label also exists and if I remove it, so there will not be label at tap bar.

Comment: remove the middle title: self.navigationItem.title = @"";  or self.navigationItem.title = nil;   ?

Comment: right, I know that, but it removes the label from the bottom from the tabbar also

Comment: then you're doing something wrong. This removes title only from navigationController navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom view to the navigation bar's `-titleView`

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = someLabel;
```

Comment: It adds the label but to the same place ignoring label's frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` which provides a way of adding a fixed padding in a navigation bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpaceItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                    target:nil
                                    action:NULL]
                                   autorelease];
fixedSpaceItem.width = 50;
UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                target:nil
                                action:NULL]
                               autorelease];
// vc is some view controller
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        fixedSpaceItem,
                                        cancelItem,
                                        nil];
```

This will right indent the "Cancel" button 50 points.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, thought you wanted to change indent of the left or right item(s).